# How does R's randomForest package calculate its constant predictions?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest, prediction

I tried to understand it, by applying an regression-tree on the `Friedman#1` dataset:

```
library("mlbench") 

dataset <- list()
random.forest <- list() 
regression.tree <- list() 
train.data.in.test.leaf <- list()
test.data.in.test.leaf <- list() 

test.leaf.size <- 0 
test.leaf.prediction <- 0 
test.leaf.index <- 1 
all.leaf.index <- matrix(1, nrow = 500, ncol = 1) 

dataset <- data.frame(mlbench.friedman1(501, sd=1))
```

Then I fitted a regression tree on the 500 first data-points in order to predict the 501-st data-point:

```
library("randomForest") 

random.forest <- randomForest(y ~ ., data=dataset[1:500,], ntree=1, nodesize=50, mtry=3)

regression.tree <- data.frame(getTree(random.forest)) 
status <- regression.tree$status; 
split.var <- regression.tree$split.var;  
split.point <- regression.tree$split.point; 


while(status[test.leaf.index] < (-1)) {
    if(dataset[501,split.var[test.leaf.index]] <= split.point[test.leaf.index]) { 
        test.leaf.index <- regression.tree$left.daughter[test.leaf.index] 
    } else { 
        test.leaf.index <- regression.tree$right.daughter[test.leaf.index] 
    } 
} 

for(i in 1:500) 
  while(status[all.leaf.index[i]] < (-1)) {
  if(dataset[i,split.var[all.leaf.index[i]]] <= split.point[all.leaf.index[i]]) { 
    all.leaf.index[i] <- regression.tree$left.daughter[all.leaf.index[i]] 
  } else { 
    all.leaf.index[i] <- regression.tree$right.daughter[all.leaf.index[i]] 
  } 
} 
end 

train.data.in.test.leaf <- dataset[all.leaf.index == test.leaf.index,]; 
test.data.in.test.leaf <- dataset[501,]; 

test.leaf.prediction <- regression.tree$prediction[test.leaf.index] 
test.leaf.prediction2 <- mean(train.data.in.test.leaf$y)

end
```

`test.leaf.index` and `all.leaf.index` are important. They give us the leaf where the test-point lies and the leaves, where all other points lie. `test.leaf.index` and `all.leaf.index` are valid. I checked them with the function:

```
get_path_to_node <- function(tree, child){
  parent <- which(tree[,'left.daughter']==child | tree[,'right.daughter']==child)
  if( parent==1 ) return(paste(parent, child, sep='->'))
  return( paste(get_path_to_node(tree, child=parent), child, sep='->' ) )
}


path <- get_path_to_node(regression.tree,test.leaf.index)
```

and by checking the split rules and split points.

Now my question is: why are `test.leaf.prediction` (=calculated with R's randomForest package) and `test.leaf.prediction2` (=calculated manually)  different?

Comment: Be aware that questions about code &/or code check are generally off topic here. Your software neutral question about RF is fine, but the code-based version may not get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how the RF-package works: The RF-package has a parameter which is called

```
randomForest(..., replace = ..., ...)
```

which is set

```
= TRUE
```

as default. If it is set to

```
= FALSE
```

and if you also set

```
randomForest(..., sampsize = nrow('of your training-data'),...)
```

a single regression tree calculates its constant prediction for leaf $ R_j $ just by $ ave(y^{(i)}: i\in N_j) $, where $ N_j = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : [(x^{(n)})^T,(y^{(n)})^T]^T \in training-data \ \land \ x^{(n)}\in R_j \} $.